# No Constraints found in viewDidLayoutSubviews - AutoLayout

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, constraints

Happy Thanksgiving if you celebrate it!

I have a `UIImageView` on storyboard, setup with 4 constraints. The center x constraint has an identifier set (via storyboard), "imageViewTwoCenterX".

I'm trying to find that constraint with the identifier.

**PROBLEM:** The code below returns `0` for the constraints array count, and never finds the constraint with the identifier.

Am I doing something wrong? Wrong practice? All help is appreciated!

I use this code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print("Constraints Count: \(imageViewTwo.constraints.count)")
    for constraint  in imageViewTwo.constraints {
        if constraint.identifier == "imageViewTwoCenterX" {
            print("Found it!")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For constraints other than width/height constraints, IB adds them to the view's `superview`. So you won't find them among the image view's constraints. Try listing its `superview`'s constraints instead.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! Will accept as answer in 7 more minutes.